# Returning a pointer using get method from class and using *& to take it in recursively

Tags: c++

So I am just working on some code and have kind of stumped myself

I have a class Node and another class BinaryTree:

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node();
    Node(int thedata, Node* right, Node* left):data(thedata), right_pointer(right),   left_pointer(left){};
    int get_data(){return data;}
    Node* get_right() {return right_pointer;}
    Node* get_left() {return left_pointer;}
private:
    int data;
    Node* right_pointer;
    Node* left_pointer;
};

class BinaryTree
{
private:
    Node* root;
    void add_tree_node(Node*& root,int data);
    void print_tree(Node* root);
public:
    BinaryTree();
    void print_tree();
    void add_tree_node(int data); 
 };
```

My issue is with this command:

add_tree_node(root->get_right(), data);

I get an error saying: no instance of overloaded function.
which get_right() returns a pointer to the pointer and was wondering if there was a better way of doing this instead of the two options below.

when I do this:
 Node* right = root->get_right();
 add_tree_node(right, data);

or

add_tree_node(root->right_link,data);

it works and I understand why it works because we are passing in the pointer itself and not the value.

Comment: Your problem is this method signiture `void add_tree_node(Node*& root,int data);`, What do you think it's suppose to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Node* &get_right() {return right_pointer;}
Node* &get_left() {return left_pointer;}
```

Answer (score 0):

`node->get_right()` returns an rvalue. `add_tree_node()` takes a non-const reference. You can only make a non-const reference out of an lvalue, not an rvalue. Therefore the return value of `node->get_right()` cannot be turned into a non-const reference unless you put it into a local variable first.

That said, why does `add_tree_node()` take a reference to begin with? It's already taking a pointer, so you can mutate the `Node` all you want without needing a reference.

Comment: I was doing by reference because I believed that the only way I could actually make changes to the root pointer. Thought I had to use ** or *& when I just use * the table does not actually update.

Comment: @BehdadJamshidi: Presumably you're adding nodes by setting `left_pointer` or `right_pointer`, yes? You can do that with just `Node*`.

Comment: @BehdadJamshidi: Oh I think I see. You're trying to modify the passed-in pointer.

Comment: @BehdadJamshidi: The only way that'll work with `get_right()` is if you change `get_left()` and `get_right()` to return references directly.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you need an insert( *& node, data) function

then in your main, you can create a new binary tree with your constructor with something like this: Node* binaryTree = new Node();
from there, you can insert nodes like this:  binaryTree->insert( binaryTree, data );